# Regular expression for number comma separated

Tags: javascript, regex, angular

I am using regEx `/^[0-9]+((?:[,][0-9]{0,20})?)$/g` .in this I am able to enter digit,digit.
but i want to add more digit.

I have created sample app on [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/comma-separated-regex-angular?file=src/app/phone-number.directive.ts)

For example digit, digit,...nth number.

Valid inputs:

```
1234567890
123,321,467,56,1
```

Invalid inputs:

```
1123,,456
,123,456,
123,
```

Comment: your explanation does not say anything about `{0,20}` in regex?

Comment: @AZ_  I don't want to add {0,20}. When i remove {0,20} from regex then i am not able to enter comma(,).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try below regex. Demo is [here](https://regex101.com/r/rc9GYt/1) .

```
^(\d+\,?)*\d+$
```

Edit:
Do the following changes in your project.

`commaSeperatedRegEx = /^(\d+\,?)+$/g;`
in your `appPhoneNumber` directive
and `const matches = control.value.match(/^(\d+\,?)*\d+$/g);`
in `app.component`

Comment: When i add ^(\d+\,?)*\d+$ then i am not able to enter comma(,).
https://stackblitz.com/edit/comma-separated-regex-angular?file=src/app/phone-number.directive.ts

Comment: You do not need to escape `,`. anyways +1

Comment: Working app https://stackblitz.com/edit/comma-separated-regex-angular-baso94